# How to filter products using filter products by attribute widget and OR logic between different product attribute types?

Tags: widgets, terms, term-meta

I have the following query url to filter products by 2 different attribute types:

```
https://www.example.com/product-category/customized-bags/?filter_wallet-type=womens-wallet&query_type_wallet-type=or&filter_bag-type=laptop-bag&query_type_bag-type=or
```

The url has 2 attributes: `wallet-type` and `bag-type`. In widget settings, I have set both attributes' widgets to have `OR` logic. However, the above url returns no products as there are no products which have `wallet-type` set as `womens-wallet` and `bag-type` set as `laptop-bag`. However, I want the query to return products which either have `wallet-type` set as `womens-wallet` OR have `bag-type` set as `laptop-bag`, which means the filtering should follow `OR` logic when different attribute types are selected.

How to do this?

Comment: Chances are high that you have to rethink the code responsible for filtering. Unfortunately, you keep the code in secret, but we can't read it remotely to suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue #1 (nested tax_query with `OR` relation)

---

After going through WordPress core and WooCommerce core, it appears
`query_type_bag-type=or` (query_type_.$attribute) query arg is only changing the value of the `operator` key on the individual taxonomy array for the attribute.

For example:

- `query_type_pa_color=and` = `operator => 'AND'`
- `query_type_pa_color=or` = `operator => 'IN'`

You can see in the screenshot below the way the tax_query is built with an example URL structure such as:

`...?filter_color=blue&query_type_color=or&filter_size=small&query_type_size=or`

The issue here is that the tax_query relation is set to 'AND' by default, and in my example we can also see there is another tax_query array for `product_visibility`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

What we want to do is nest the tax_queries for our attributes and set a relation on that nested tax_query to `OR`.

Example of our nested tax_query:

[image]

To achieve this you need to hook onto the `pre_get_posts` filter, an example below is provided (modify the attributes to suite your configuration):

```php
add_filter(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {

        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

            $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );

            // get the index of each taxonomy set in the tax_query
            $taxonomy_indexes = array_column( $tax_query, 'taxonomy' );

            $allowed = array(
                'pa_color',
                'pa_size',
            );

            // set nested query relation to OR
            $nested_tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

            foreach ( $taxonomy_indexes as $key => $taxonomy ) {

                if ( ! in_array( $taxonomy, $allowed ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                // push each taxonomy onto new array
                $nested_tax_query[] = $tax_query[ $key ];

                // we don't want this taxonomy in the initial tax_query
                // as it was provided in $query->query_vars['tax_query']
                unset( $tax_query[ $key ] );

            }

            // put our nested query back onto $tax_query ( $query->get('tax_query') )
            $tax_query[] = $nested_tax_query;

            // overwrite $query->query_vars['tax_query'] with newly built $tax_query array
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

        }

    }
);
```

This will give you the result you are after.

UPDATE:

### Issue #2 (WooCommerce attribute widget hides unmatched terms/taxonomies after `$_GET` request)

---

To answer your other question in the comments regarding how the WooCommerce attribute widget works.

> This resolves the above stated issue. However, in default woocommerce filter by attribute widget, the attributes for bag-type do not show when we have filtered with wallet-type using this url - https://www.example.com/product-category/customized-bags/?filter_wallet-type=womens-wallet&query_type_wallet-type=or. How to resolve this?

I ran a test and I see that issue is unfortunately the way that WooCommerce attribute widget is designed. Whatever attributes you select and filter (as seen in the URL), the widget then excludes all the other terms of that attribute taxonomy and also any other attribute taxonomies themselves, in your case `bag-type`.

The class responsible for generating the widget is:

- `woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php`

There are filters/hooks in there you could probably adjust to work   around this. But... I would just create my own filters instead of   using the WooCommerce one (if it were me). In fact you could probably    extend the WooCommerce widget with a sub class and overwrite methods    too.

E.g. `class Custom_WC_Widget_Layered_Nav extends WC_Widget_Layered_Nav {}`

The class `WC_Widget_Layered_Nav` is already extending `WC_Widget` which then extends `WP_Widget`.

Refer to:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_widget/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this resolves the above stated issue. However, in default woocommerce filter by attribute widget, the attributes for `bag-type` do not show when we have filtered with `wallet-type` using this url - `https://www.example.com/product-category/customized-bags/?filter_wallet-type=womens-wallet&query_type_wallet-type=or`. How to resolve this?

Comment: @dc09 please refer to updated answer, it was too long for a comment, I try to provide you some context as to what is happening and how you can potentially work around it if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I was able to solve this by adding a filter in `get_filtered_term_product_counts` function in `Filterer.php` file in woocommerce to edit `$tax_query`

Comment: @dc09 nice, glad you got it sorted.